# apache service not stopping in xampp

Tags: xampp

I tried to stop the apache service in xampp, but it does not stop from running and it shows up an error "Busy...ERROR: -1" What is the cause of this problem of how do I resolve this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you try to stop it? What error message specifically did you get? Did you get any error or warning notices in the log files?

Comment: In order to stop the Apache Service in XAMPP, you must run the xampp-control.exe as ADMINISTRATOR.

Navigate to your XAMPP Directory, right-click xampp-control.exe, and select Run as Administrator.  If the application is already running, open it from the tray, select [EXIT] button, then try to run xampp-control.exe as administrator.

Answer (score 12):

What OS are you using?
Are you using the XAMPP control panel?

In windows press

```
Start
Run
Type "Services.msc"
Find the "Apache" service
Right click and stop
```

I find i get this error if i start the apache service without the control panel but try to stop it with the control panel.

Comment: Its in a stopping status. Not in start or stop. how to handle this