# XAMPP Tomcat Not Stopping

Tags: windows, apache, tomcat, xampp

I have XAMPP installed on my Windows machine,
I am unable to stop the Tomcat server.

I have tried to kill the process with the Process Id as well, 
But weirdly it's not showing in the Task Manager nor the local Services,
Which I referred from here -
[apache service not stopping in xampp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8414292/apache-service-not-stopping-in-xampp)

**Here's my XAMPP Control Panel screenshot -**
[image]

**Here's the Task Manager, I can't find the Process ID 3104 as shown in the XAMPP Control Panel-**

[image]

**I did run the command "Services.msc" to find and stop it but, no luck there either.**

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should check the PID and verify that it is not associated with any other service/process mistaken for Tomcat by XAMPP.

In my case I had Jenkins running on port 8080 and starting XAMPP it was "guessing" that Tomcat was already running:

[image: Tomcat detected as already running]

---

In reality, looking at the PID (198092 in my case) it was associated with java.exe:

[image: java.exe]

and this was a process generated by my Jenkins server running on that port:

[image: Jenkins On]

This is why you cannot stop Tomcat from there... (it is not Tomcat running on 8080).

---

To verify this and properly start Tomcat you can try this:

Stopping Jenkins:

[image: Jenkins Off]

Will remove the service running on 8080 and XAMPP is able to correctly detect that Tomcat is not running:

[image: Tomcat not running]

At this point you can Start Tomcat in XAMPP (and it should start for real this time):

[image: Tomcat running]

Going to the localhost page, port 8080 you will have a proof of it:

[image: Tomcat Page]

If you want you can now successfully stop it from XAMPP:

[image: Tomcat Stop]

Answer (score 0):

On Windows:
XAMPP opens a shell(CMD) on starting tomcat just close that shell.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.